# How to bring a list item to front from gridview in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating a media player system in which am listing some songs using grid view.  In our application we can drag one song from the list and drop it on a specified area. These all functionalities have been implemented. But the problem is while am dragging, the item is being dragged behind of the other items in the grid view.
 (ie, If am listing 3 songs, first song is behind of the other 2 songs. second song is behind of the 3rd song but in front of the first song).

Am trying to bring the grid item to front when it is about to drag and drop.
Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: You might look into one of your older questions. I answered it there already. If you switch the code-snippets for your "specified area" with the gridview, such that the code for the gridview comes after the code for the "specified area", it will be layerd above it. Alternatively, you can set the z-property of the gridview to a larger value than the one of the "specified area" (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop)

Comment: Thanks for your support. But the code for grid view is already above all layers. That's not the issue. Issue is between the grid item layering of the grid view. I need to bring the selected grid item on above all other grid items in the same grid view.

Comment: Then you might set the z-value of the GridItem to a positive value, as long as the drag is active.

Comment: For as long as not absolutely necessary, I would not recommend to reparent it to another layer, as this would come with various issues, when the drag will not be be completed.

Comment: But am not able to set the z value of the GridItem. It is not working.

Comment: You are right. I never realized this behavior. So it seems you need to resort to the solution of ddriver

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dragging the original object, you can create a dedicated drag icon item, and parent it to an invisible item that's on top of the grid view, this way it will be on top of every element in the grid. Create the item when the drag begins and destroy it when the drag ends.

Comment: but can we propogate the pressed event of the orginal item to the drag icon.

Comment: You don't have to propagate anything, the drag item can be totally unrelated to the one that initiated the drag.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @derM you may work on z index of GridItem. Here is a sample code that may help you with the same:

Note: The part that concerns your question is the code inside `onPressed` event of `MouseArea` within GridItem.

```
Rectangle{
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    GridView{
        Rectangle{ anchors.fill: parent; color: 'blue'; opacity: 0.2; }
        id: musicBox
        width: 500; height: 500
        model: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        delegate: Rectangle{
            id: songItem
            border{ width: 2; color: 'blue'}
            width: 100; height: 100
            color: (musicBox.currentIndex == index) ? 'yellow' : 'red'

            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: songItem
                drag{
                    minimumX: 0
                    minimumY: 0
                    maximumX: musicBox.width
                    maximumY: musicBox.height
                    axis: Drag.XandYAxis
                    target: songItem
                }
                onPressed:{
                    for(var i = 0; i < musicBox.count; i++){ musicBox.currentIndex = i; musicBox.currentItem.z = i; }
                    musicBox.currentIndex = index
                    musicBox.currentItem.z = musicBox.count
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```